# Nuxeo Create and Update file with new Version Using REST

Tags: java, api, rest, version, nuxeo

I am Creating a Spring-Java Application where i am Using Nuxeo as File Storage.

I want to create a new file in document with new version in nuxeo using rest api.
For example i have create a file with name of "file1.docx" in myworkspace now.
i want to update file with new version in same document. i want to use if any rest api available for this operation.

I have tried many solutions from google and nuxeo docs but it will creates new document every time. as i want to update file version only.

I have Used below service to updates file but it doesn't updates version.
/nuxeo/site/api/v1/id/{idOfTheDoc}

Also, I have Used Below Service for Create File but it creates new doc every time.
/nuxeo/site/api/v1/id/{idOfParentDoc}

Thank you for Help

Answer (score 2):

To clarify how to do it using the last version of the JavaScript Client. Here is a small JSFiddle that uploads a new blob and increments the minor version on an existing document.
Ensure you have correctly configure CORS on your server, and set a correct document path.

http://jsfiddle.net/arnaudke/he1murjL/7/

```
doc.set({'file:content': res.blob})
   .save({
     headers: {'X-Versioning-Option': 'minor'}
   });
```

HIH

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two things to take into account there:

1. If you end up creating a document instead of updating it, that means you are using the `POST` method. You should be using the `PUT` method instead for an update.
2. As mentioned by @user3885965, to create a version you need to send a `X-Versioning-Option` header, but value can either be `minor` (create a minor version, such as 1.x where x will be incremented) or `major` (create a major version, such as x.0 where x will be incremented). There is no functional difference between them, it's just there for you to choose which number you'd like to increment.

Answer (score 0):

When updating the document you should use the specific header "
X-Versioning-Option: MAJOR" as stated in [REST API](https://doc.nuxeo.com/x/mwM5AQ) documentation